# Unique Key for Integer Array and two Boolean Arrays

Tags: hashmap, key, hashtable, memoization

I am struggling to make a function, which will make a key for this kind of paramters:

```
int[] pos | int[] ongoing | int[] completed 
{17, 10}  | {1,0,0,1}     | {0,1,0,0}

pos[0] < 200
pos[1] < 200
```

The integers in pos array will always be less than 200.

I need this key to make memoization for my TSP problem. I make a key every recursion call and check if that key already exists in my memo array.

One solution I found:

```
Map <String, Integer> states = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

And then just making String key like this:

```
public String makeKey() {
        String key = "";
        key += pos[0];
        key += pos[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < ongoing.length; i++) {
            key += ongoing[i];
            key += completed[i];
        }
        return key;
    }
```

And checking if key exists in the memo:

```
State curState = new State(pos, ongoing, completed);
    String key = curState.makeKey();
    if (states.containsKey(key)) {
        return states.get(key);
    }
```

But the problem is that **the assignment doesn't allow me to use java.util.***. So now I am trying to make a hash table but I don't know how to make hash function for these kind of parameters.